# xPath to get parent node position using count

Tags: xpath

My xml looks like the following. The focus is at the third level: `<name>`,`<address>` etc. I'd like to find the position of parent `<customer>`.

I use "`count(../preceding-sibling::*) + 1`" but it doesn't return a count when the node is empty. How do I fix this? Thanks.

```
<record>
    <customer>
        <name>Sue A</name>                  -- return 1
        <address>123 Main St</address>      -- return 1
        <phone></phone>                     -- missing
        <status>A</status>                  -- return 1
    </customer>
    <customer>
        <name>John B</name>                 -- return 2
        <address></address>                 -- missing
        <phone>123-456-7890</phone>         -- return 2
        <status></status>                   -- missing
    </customer>
    …
</record>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.  You've left out how you're establishing the current node when evaluating your XPath.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is lacking a lot of information, using the following xquery It looks like your logic is correct, however you are probably using the text nodes as current nodes instead of the element node.

This query returns the same wrong results, because some text nodes are missing:

```
let $x := 
  for $grandchild in //customer/*/text()  
  return count($grandchild/../../preceding-sibling::*) + 1
return $x
```

This query returns correct results, because every element exists:

```
let $x := 
  for $child in //customer/*  
  return count($child/../preceding-sibling::*) + 1
return $x
```

Selecting the element node as current node will probably fix any issue.